# Outlook Email Signature and hyperlink line color

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, responsive

Does anyone have a solution for changing the color of the hyperlink line (from blue) on desktop and mobile devices?

CSS and Html styling have not been able to prevent the blue line from showing up, though we have been able to remove the line altogether on desktop.  The phone seems to have an override with this.

My client would like the hyperlink line to be a brand color, while the text remains black.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

some CSS file use custom CSS on different screen media width.
maybe you should override it too on different media?
try to search or add like :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    a {
     color: red;
     text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just tried... unfortunately the phone still turns the underline to blue.

Comment: i have modified above code. may be it will work.
here is the [screenshot](https://d1sz9tkli0lfjq.cloudfront.net/items/09162e1a0E0p3O0T0H2E/Screen%20Recording%202019-10-22%20at%2007.39%20PM.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found exactly what you're looking for, just change the colors in the code below. The underline hight is set to 3px, but you can change it to whatever you want, make sure to change all the colors, because when the link is visited it turns purple by default.

```css
a {
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
color: #222831;
border-bottom: 3px solid #00adb5;
}
a:visited {
color: Purple;
border-bottom: 3px solid purple;
}
a:hover {
color: black;
border-bottom: 3px solid #222831;
}
```

```html
<a href="www.enter/url.com">Link Text</a>
```

Comment: Hi.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work.  The problem seems to be that Outlook (and the mobile device) override a lot of css coding - the above should have worked though.

Answer (score -1):

Make the link into a button, Here is an example, just paste the link into the Html and edit the CSS colors.

```css
.color-link {
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #00adb5
}
```

```html
<button class= "color-link" onclick="window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com/search';">Link Text</button>
```

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but buttons are apparently not accepted by outlook or the phone.  I make it correctly in HTML, and the email and phone just translate it into a simply hyperlink (blue text with blue underline.